# $X \cap A = X\setminus B \iff X \cap (M\setminus A) = B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A \subseteq M, X \subseteq M \text{ and } B\subseteq X$

I want to prove the following biconditional statement:

$X \cap A = X\setminus B \iff X \cap (M\setminus A) = B$

I did as follows, but I'm not sure if I did it right

$X \cap A = X\setminus B$

$\Leftrightarrow X \cap A = X \cap B^\complement$

$\Leftrightarrow X \setminus (X \cap A) = X \setminus (X \cap B^\complement)$

$\Leftrightarrow X \setminus A = X \setminus B^\complement$

$\Leftrightarrow X \cap A^\complement = X \cap B$

$\Leftrightarrow (X \cap A^\complement) \cap M = B$

$\Leftrightarrow X \cap (M \cap A^\complement) = B$

$\Leftrightarrow X \cap (M \setminus A) = B$

Is this correct?

Comment: That all looks correct to me, yeah

Comment: @StephenDonovan Thank you.

Comment: It's correct but the 4th line of your proof should be erased.

Comment: BTW, there is an available tag "proof-verification".

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, Thank you, edited.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution :
$$X\cap A = X \setminus B=X\cap B^c \implies A=B^c \implies A^c=B$$
and
$$X\cap(M\setminus A)=X\cap A^c =X\cap B=B$$